# Why is the "on_update" option not present in Django Relationship fields?

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

I'm using Django 3.0 + MariaDB.
I've created a models.py from an existent database with the "python manage.py inspectdb > models.py" command.
I need now to set the options for the Foreign Keys.
As you know in a database you can have multiple options for the Foreign Keys: the first classic is "ON_DELETE" and the second is 'ON_UPDATE' (You can even have more options in PostgreSQL). 
In Django, there is just an "on_delete", but no "on_update" option, what I found very surprising.
I found nothing on the official documentation about this. 
Neither on some old posts with the same question, the responses were not conclusive and focused on the "on_delete".
I'm asking about the "ON_UPDATE' option, nothing else.
So, where is this option, or why is it not present in Django's ORM ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with on_update but you cannot do in Django without it

Comment: Well, if you need to change an id for any reason (generally for fixing wrong data), the linked data can be updated too with the "on_update" option.
My database is configured so, and it works pretty well.
And without this option it could be laborious , specially with millions of entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not actually use database cascade options even for [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

> on_delete doesn’t create an SQL constraint in the database. Support
>   for database-level cascade options may be implemented later.

There are convenient advantages of the following as your app can react to `pre_delete` and `post_delete` signals, but there is also slight disadvantage in terms of performance

---

Regarding `ON_UPDATE`

It was not implemented and it was fairly rarely used as normally you would never change your model id's

You still can create SQL migration if you need something specific on database level or emulate it on application level for better control (for instance overriding model save method)

---

Regarding additional database constraints not related to foreign key, there are docs related to them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/) and specific to postgreSQL [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/constraints/)

Comment: I have nothing specific, I just want to be sure that the linked data are updated if the primary keys are modified for any reason. That's the purpose of the ON_UPDATE option.

Comment: I think I'll just keep it as it is in the database.
If I understand correctly, the Django ORM will not access this option, which is what I wanted to be sure of.