# ForeignKey updates aren't cascading on Django created tables in Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

This is the error that I get when I try to update the value in the "parent" table that the foreign key is looking at in a related table:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "product" violates foreign key constraint "pd_family_product_guid_ada83db3_fk_product_guid" on table "pd_family"
DETAIL:  Key (guid)=(902d30b8-26ba-ea11-a812-000d3a5bbb60) is still referenced from table "pd_family".
SQL state: 23503
```

This is what I have for my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    guid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    previous_product_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class StandardProductFieldsMixin(models.Model):
    product_guid = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='product_guid')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ActiveFieldMixin(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Family(StandardProductFieldsMixin, ActiveFieldMixin):
    new_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    code = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField(null=True)
    fam_desc = models.TextField(null=True)
```

When I try to change a value of `guid` in `Product`, my expectation is that it would automatically change it in `Family` as well. I'm trying to change it with something like:

```
UPDATE product
SET guid = '902D30B8-26BA-EA11-A812-000D3A5BBB6B'
WHERE guid = '902D30B8-26BA-EA11-A812-000D3A5BBB60'
```

I guess I was under the wrong impression. Do I need to do something additional in the model? Looked at the documentation for something like `on_update`, but not seeing that either an `**options` or as a parameter for `models.ForeignKey`.

From what I gather after reading about it for more than an hour, if I want this kind of functionality I just need to add it Postgres manual, by dropping the constraint and adding it back with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32530563/4151233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I'm under the wrong impression:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648910/3123109

Sounds like Django model migrations implement neither `ON DELETE` nor `ON UPDATE` database `CASCADES` options. I guess I'd need to drop into the database and implement them there.